# How do I create global variables?

Tags: c#, variables

Just started out, I'm purely confused about variable scopes.
Why won't this work? How do I make this work? Could anyone possibly help me? Why doesn't the variable work in the main method?
[I'm already assured that this question will get reported/locked for some unknown reason that I don't know about]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingC
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void First()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            public const string apple = "good!";
            Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
            Console.ReadLine();
            First();
            Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare `apple` in the class, not the method. It is limited to the method's scope.

Comment: Please do not edit the fundamental question as it can invalidate any previous answers. If you have another question, feel free to create a new question. I would, however, highly recommend you read tutorials for C# first.

Comment: @LeDirt I would take the time out to google some of the many excellent `C# for beginners Tutorials` that are on line and focus on the following `Variables, Methods, Scope, Encapsulation, difference between Instance methods vs static methods`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer, is that the "Brackets" define the scope.

Any time you declare a variable, if you want to know where you can use it, find out what set of brackets it is inside.  In your case, apple only applies to Main.  First cannot see it, because it is declared at a different level.  Only the things that are also inside the same set of brackets as a variable can see it.

Also note, its the FIRST set of brackets, going outward from the variable.  So starting at the declaration for apple, you go out to the brackets around main.  That describes the scope of apple.

Comment: This does describe the variable scope, but once actual objects start coming into play, it should be noted that accessors will define the usage scope. In the case of the public `apple`, it is no longer limited to the scope of the class, as anything will be able to access it. Also +1 for the explanation  ;)

Comment: modifiers like public/private/protected have an affect across classes.  When within the same class they can all be ignored for the most part.  Now, if you have a global variable `private const string apple` in this class, and then declare another class somewhere else, that second class couldn't see it.  However if it were `public` instead, then the second class would be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

this will do that bro!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestingC
{
public class Program
  {
    public const string apple = "good!";
    public static void First()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
        Console.ReadLine();
        First();
        Console.WriteLine("Apple is: " + apple);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `First()` needs to be static.

Comment: Alright, but an error comes up that "{" is missing.

Comment: Nope, that is not Missing, Review the code bro @LeDirt

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `apple` is defined within `Main`. You can only use it inside that method.
To use it inside the `First()` method, you need to declare `apple` at the class level.

Put `public static const string apple = "good!";`

just below  `public class Program
          {`

I suggest you do some reading about scope of variables. True global variables don't exist in C#.

EDIT: Added `static`, as pointed out by Steve.

Comment: error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.First()'

Also, Steve, can you tell me what is the "another problem"?

Comment: @LeDirt Steve is correct - you need to make it `static` - `public static const string apple = "good!";`

Comment: First needs to be static as well. Static things aren't able to see non-static things.  The reason for that is rather long and convoluted....but also involves scope

Comment: **still confused by the meanings of public/static/consts**
http://pastebin.com/TkGB4F3e

Doesn't want to work. error CS0131: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer
How I make it so I can change the variable value? Also I want to define the variable inside a function, uhh, I'm still confused.

Comment: @LeDirt `const` means constant - you can't change it afterwards. Remove `const` to be able to change the value in your method.
Your code in pastebin still doesn't have the `static` on `apple` - see the line in my answer starting with "Put"

Answer (score 0):

The variable is only visible from the scope you declared it in, which in this case is in the Main method. Generally, in C# (and in mot other C family languages), that means between the curly brackets.
Your apple var would also be visible in nested scope (another pair of brackets {} inside Main).
If you want a variable to be visible in both your methods, you have to declare it as a member of the Program class (inside the class but outside of any method)

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to:

"EDIT: How do I create a variable inside a function that can be accessed by other functions?"

(which is no longer there, but I think was you clarifying your question)

The short answer is that you can't, at least not in the way you're implying.

Variables defined in a method are local variables, held on the stack frame, meaning they can only be accessed within the method, unless they are passed into another method as a variable, or back out of this method as the return value, or as an `out` or `ref` parameter.

You could pass the string as a parameter to the `First` method.

So, change the `First` method to have a parameter:

```
public static void First(string stringToPassIn)
{
    ...
}
```

And call it with the argument:

```
First(apple);
```

You would acces it in the method with `stringToPassIn` then.

You should probably learn about passing by reference and passing by value, for reference types and value type, respectively.

See this for starters 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

If you wanted something declared in `First` to be accessible in `Main`, you could use `out` or `ref` parameters, depending on your needs.

Again, learning about methods in C# would be a good idea